# I'm [eager] to evaluate this tag

Tags: discussion, retag-request

[eager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/eager) is mainly about eager loading, which has the tag [eager-loading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/eager-loading). Some questions have [eager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/eager) [loading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/loading), whereas tags should make sense on their own. Some are about the opposite of lazy evaluation, which has the tag [lazy-evaluation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/lazy-evaluation).

Questions with [eager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/eager) should be evaluated to see whether they're about databases or about functional programming, and retagged accordingly. Let's not be lazy!

Answer (score 14):

This is fairly quick to do since there's a handful, but be careful:

- Some of these questions *don't* talk about eager loading at all.
- Most of these questions require *further* editing - don't just remove the tag.
- We should look for a corollary tag that covers eager evaluation, which is *slightly* different than eager loading.

Answer (score -2):

The corollary tag for eager evaluation as opposed to [lazy-evaluation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/lazy-evaluation) exists under the name [strictness](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/strictness).

Comment: Doesn't look like it.  Why would I think "strictness" when I think "eager evaluation"?  The tag is also expressly bound to Haskell in its usage description.

Comment: @Makoto I agree it doesn't sound correct -- but that's the tag that happens to cover the correct concept as far as I can tell. If the tag is expressly bound to haskell at the moment, that's just a matter of editing the tag wiki...

Comment: @sclv: And renaming the tag, and [tagging everything which is not Haskell](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/strictness%20not%20haskell?mode=all).

Comment: @Kevin what are you talking about? I was just pointing out a tag exists to discuss eager evaluation, it just so happens to be named "strictness". You seem to be arguing against a proposal I didn't make. All I did was provide a fact, not make any proposal at all!

Comment: @sclv: I interpreted "that's just a matter of editing the tag wiki..." as such a proposal.  I would also point out that, given this is *not* a proposal, it does not answer OP's question.

Comment: "that's just a matter of editing the tag wiki" was simply in response to the comment that the tag is bound to Haskell in the usage description.